# Dependency Injection object creation clarification

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm putting together a unit testing training class for C# developers.  I can debug through the code and see what's happening in some simple dependency injection examples.  But I can't find the words / phrases to accurately describe what is happening when we create a class object and pass it a new Service.

Two questions.

How is this

```
var test = new Service();
Client client = new Client(test);
```

different that this?

```
Client client = new Client(new Service());
```

And what is the term used for the Service in this example?

```
new Client(new Service());
```

Comment: Where is the dependency injection here? Without defining Service and Client this is just a slow Tuesday in C#.

Comment: @PepitoSh When you inject a dependency (here Service via constructor) you have Dependency Injection.

Comment: There is no difference, and it’s called a dependency.

Comment: Passing an object in a constructor does not qualify as dependency injection. The passed object must meet certain criteria, implement interfaces, etc. This is why I find this question vague.

Comment: @PepitoSh If Client depends on Service and you can control the Service from outside (pass it via constructor or setter) we are talking about DI or IoC. Period. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) *A dependency is an object that can be used (a service). An injection is the passing of a dependency to a dependent object (a client) that would use it. The service is made part of the client's state.[1] Passing the service to the client, rather than allowing a client to build or find the service, is the fundamental requirement of the pattern.*

Comment: @PepitoSh: I think you are confusing the Dependency Injection *pattern* (DI) with the use of a *DI Container*. DI does not require the use of a DI Container. All examples shown by OP are examples of DI, and more specifically, [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

Comment: @Steven, Sir Rufo: Thank you, I will remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var test = new Service();
> Client client = new Client(test);
> ```

In this example, the `Service` **dependency** is stored in a *variable* and is **injected** into the **consumer** `Client`, using **constructor injection**.

> ```
> Client client = new Client(new Service());
> ```

In this example, the `Service` **dependency** is injected directly into `Client`'s constructor.

> And what is the term used for the Service in this example?

In this case, `Service` is the **dependency** and `Client` is the **consumer**. They are both **components**. In case `Client` depends on `IService`, `IService` is the **service** or **abstraction**, while `Service` is its **implementation**, or more generally: the **component**.

A **component** is an application class that contains application logic. Components are the vocal point of DI, since you build up **object graphs** of **components**. The opposite or **components** are data centric objects, such as entities, DTOs, messages, view models, etc. They don't contain any behavior and are typically passed through method calls on initialized **object graphs**.

For a complete terminology, see [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl).

Comment: The first couple of paragraphs might be a *source code* distinction, as the final IL will be identical unless you're using the `test` variable for something else.